# Please give me some advice on references of complex geometry

Tags: book-recommendation, complex-geometry

Recently I am reading complex geometry and preparing for my complex geometry exam. Our lectures book is so disorder and brief that I have to consult Wikipedia and math-overflow. I need some materials of complex geometry such as almost complex manifolds, Kähler manifolds, complex and holomorphic vector bundles, Hodge theory, Chern classes and sheaf theory. So can you recommend some complex geometry lectures or books to me?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found these notes very helpful: www.caramdir.at/uploads/math/piii-cm/complex-manifolds.pdf  They are based on the course at my university though, so they may or may not be relevant. My friend says that the book by Huybrechts is good too.

Comment: @KennyWong okay,thank you very much

Comment: Is the document @Kenny Wong has indicated you what you mean when you ask about "complex geometry" or do you need more elementary "figure geometry" on lines, circles trated by complex methods, till "conformal mapping"...

Comment: @JeanMarie I mean some content of complex geometry such as almost complex manifolds ,Kähler manifolds, complex and holomorphic vector bundles,Hodge theory, Chern classes and sheaf theory.

Comment: Did you look at the book of Voisin about Hodge theory ?

Comment: @N.H. No,I haven't learned hodge theory systematically.Is that book very suitable to learn on hodge theory?thank you!

Comment: I don't know, I just did the first chapters one year ago when I needed some results. I remember it was very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know a complete book of complex geometry as you wish; therefore I print here a list of books with a brief overview on their.

1. Ballmann W. - *Lectures on Kähler Manifolds.* A nice text devoted to Kähler manifolds.
2. Huybrechts D. - *Complex Geometry. An Introduction.* A very complete
   text on subject, with two appendicies: one on Hodge theory and the
   other one on sheaves cohomology.
3. Kobayashi S. - *Differential Geometry of Complex Vector Bundles.* A clear and complete text on holomorphic vector bundles.
4. Voisin C. - *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry, Volumes I and II.* "The texts of Hodge theory."

Comment: Wow, very useful! Thank you very much!