# References for Kähler manifolds

Tags: reference-request, kahler-manifolds

I'm interested in the symplectic coordinates of a Kähler manifold and how the metric is expressed in such coordinates. I guess these computations will be in standard references for Kähler manifolds. Can you recommend me some of them, please?

Comment: You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287748/please-give-me-some-advice-on-references-of-complex-geometry/2294801#2294801)! ;)

Comment: You are welcome. ;)